# Find the Eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> Find the Eigenvector of the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}3 & 1 & 1\\2&4&2\\1&1&3\end{pmatrix}$ corresponding to Eigenvalue $\lambda=2 $.

The Eigen values of $A$ are $\lambda =2,2,6$. It is easy to find the Eigenvector corresponding to Eigen value $\lambda =6$, the one i find using  Cramer's rule is $(1, 2, 1)$. But i am unable to find the Eigenvector corresponding to Eigenvalue $\lambda =2$ (Cramer's rule fails here).

Comment: What have you tried? How did you find the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda = 6$? Can you extend that to $\lambda = 2$?

Comment: @Calvin Lin i tried using Cramer's rule

Comment: There may be multiple eigenvectors. In that case, find a pair of eigenvectors that spans the space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the kernel of $A-2I$:

$\begin{pmatrix}1 &1 &1 \\ 2 &2 &2 \\ 1 &1 &1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=0$

$x+y+z=0$

Example eigenvectors are $\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix},$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$.

(Only two of those are linearly independent.)

Comment: How did you get these? Are you assigning $0$ to one of the variables and give arbitrary constant value to one of the remaining variables? Can we assign any real numbers in this fashion?

Comment: two of the variables could be anything and the third one has to be the opposite of their sum

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What is the null space of $A - 2 I$?

Comment: Sorry  i didn't get